# How to wrap a function around a reactive expression in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

### Minimal working example

Say I want to have a custom version of `renderDataTable`, which I shall name `myRenderDataTable` and works by wrapping around `renderDataTable`:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = basicPage(
        actionButton("button", "Increase input"),
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("table1", shiny::dataTableOutput("table1")),
            tabPanel("table2", shiny::dataTableOutput("table2")),
            tabPanel("table3", shiny::dataTableOutput("table3"))
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        myRenderDataTable <- function(a) {
            renderDataTable(
                data.frame(x = a, y = a^2, z = a^3),
                options = list(bPaginate = as.logical(a %% 2))
            )
        }
        output$table1 <- myRenderDataTable(input$button)
        output$table2 <- myRenderDataTable(input$button + 1)
        output$table3 <- myRenderDataTable(input$button + 2)
    }
))
```

### Issue

Unfortunately, it appears that `myRenderDataTable` is not reactive like `renderDataTable`. Clicking the `Increase input` button should cause the table values to change, but doesn't.

So what's going wrong?

### Attempt: Passing calls to [`reactive`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/is.reactive):

Doing `output$table1 <- reactive(myRenderDataTable(input$button))`) leads to:

```
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error : evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

### Attempt: Passing calls to [`observe`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/observe):

Doing `observe(output$table1 <- myRenderDataTable(input$button))` had no effect on the issue

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `input$button` is evaluated "eagerly" - i.e. `input$button + 1` evaluates to 2 to the first time it's run and then never changes again. You can make it evaluate every time `input$button` changes by explicitly making it a reactive:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = basicPage(
    actionButton("button", "Increase input"),
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("table1", shiny::dataTableOutput("table1")),
      tabPanel("table2", shiny::dataTableOutput("table2")),
      tabPanel("table3", shiny::dataTableOutput("table3"))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    myRenderDataTable <- function(a) {
      renderDataTable(
        data.frame(x = a(), y = a()^2, z = a()^3),
        options = list(bPaginate = as.logical(a() %% 2))
      )
    }
    output$table1 <- myRenderDataTable(reactive(input$button))
    output$table2 <- myRenderDataTable(reactive(input$button + 1))
    output$table3 <- myRenderDataTable(reactive(input$button + 2))
  }
))
```

Comment: Thanks @hadley, but it appears the `bPaginate` option still does not get evaluated even after `input$button` changes. The tables do not change from their initial pagination state.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're underestimating how much magic goes in in the render* functions. From looking at this example, I don't think you want a custom `renderDataTable` function, I think you want a custom function to build a table, which you can then pass to the built in `renderDataTable`. I think this does what you want, the wrapping is just in the opposite order (ie, a custom funciton inside a reactive expression):

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = basicPage(
        actionButton("button", "Increase input"),
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("table1", dataTableOutput("table1")),
            tabPanel("table2", dataTableOutput("table2")),
            tabPanel("table3", dataTableOutput("table3"))
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        myDataTable <- function(a) {
            data.frame(x = a, y = a^2, z = a^3)
        }
        output$table1 <- renderDataTable(myDataTable(input$button))
        output$table2 <- renderDataTable(myDataTable(input$button + 1))
        output$table3 <- renderDataTable(myDataTable(input$button + 2))
    }
))
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the code you posted above I don't see you having changed anything from what I did originally. Also, I *do* want a custom `renderDataTable` function - I have revised the code I posted in my question to reflect this. Specifically, I now want the datatable to have pagination (`bPaginate` option) set dynamically (a little contrived, I know).

Comment: alexwhan I hope you don't mind, I edited your code to match your explanation.